# Child schema not working mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to access a child schema in my city's schema, but I seem to be writing up the code in my controller incorrectly. (The error I get is that Bar is not defined):

Controller:

```
 exports.updateBar = function(req,res) {
  City.findById(req.params.id, function(err, city) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!city) { return res.send(404); }
    Bar.findById(req.params.barId, function(err, bar) {
      var updated = _merge(bar, req.body);
      updated.save(function (err) {
        if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
        return res.json(200, bar);
      });
    })
  });
};
```

Model:

```
    'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var barSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    going: Number,
    location: String
});

var CitySchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  bars: [barSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bar', barSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('City', CitySchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting  `Bar` model first and then again exporting `City`. So only `City` is exported. Replace those two lines with:

```
...
exports.Bar = mongoose.model('Bar', barSchema);
exports.City = mongoose.model('City', CitySchema);
```

then require them like this:

```
var models = require('models'),
    City = models.City,
    Bar = models.Bar
```